# Why does he deserialize twice

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization, binary-serialization

This is not my code I just have to understand it.  The original programmer cannot be reached.
dobj is just an object type.
My main question is: **Why does he deserialize again when dobj was never changed?**
Please ignore all his goto's for right now they are everywhere in this program.

```
        ////////////////////////
        //Deserialize Original//
        ////////////////////////
        dobj = Generics.IO.BinarySerializer.Open(g_PathToTMP);

        if (dobj == null)
        {
            ///////
            //LOG//
            ///////

            goto Label_Done;
        }

        dccmcaltered = dobj as ASM001.MatSettings;

        if (dccmcaltered == null)
            goto Label_Done;
        //

        //////////////////////////////////////////
        //Apply Changes To Deserialized Original//
        //////////////////////////////////////////
        dccmcaltered.ObjectLocation = wpuiobj.ObjectLocation;
        dccmcaltered.ObjectOffset = wpuiobj.ObjectOffset;
        dccmcaltered.UserDefinedLocation = wpuiobj.UserDefinedLocation;
        dccmcaltered.Locked = wpuiobj.Locked;
        dccmcaltered.RinseLocation = wpuiobj.RinseLocation;
        dccmcaltered.RinseDepth = wpuiobj.RinseDepth;
        dccmcaltered.DrainLocation = wpuiobj.DrainLocation;
        dccmcaltered.DrainDepth = wpuiobj.DrainDepth;
        //

        ////////////////////////
        //Deserialize Original//Why did we need to Deserialize again
        ////////////////////////
        dobj = Generics.IO.BinarySerializer.Open(g_PathToTMP);

        if (dobj == null)
        {
            ///////
            //LOG//
            ///////

            goto Label_Done;
        }

        dccmcoriginal = dobj as ASM001.MatSettings;
        if (dccmcoriginal == null)
            goto Label_Done;
        //

        bResult = Generics.IO.SerializerPlus.IsBinaryEqual(dccmcoriginal, dccmcaltered);

        Label_Done:
        ;

        bCurrent = bResult;

        ///////////
        //Cleanup//
        ///////////
        FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo(g_PathToTMP);

        if (fInfo.Exists)
            fInfo.Delete();
        //

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLineIf(!bCurrent && g_bVerbose, "[Main] Mat is not Current [ASM = 1]!");
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLineIf(bCurrent && g_bVerbose, "[Main] Mat is Current! [ASM = 0]");
```

**Edit** I added the rest of the method

Comment: OMG why are you/whoever using `goto`....

Comment: He was fired right? Is the code exactly the same as the original workflow after he deserialized a 2nd time? Could be as simple as a copy paste issue. Just looks like an oversight and no real reason. Any answer will be pure assumption.

Comment: Basically, it's because he's a bad programmer. That's unnecessary code right there, and the `goto` just reinforces my assumption.

Comment: This should go straight to [codecrap.com](http://codecrap.com/)

Comment: Your edit clearly shows he is checking the original vs the altered object. That's why the two deserialize calls.

Comment: `dobj` is just a placeholder variable. This code deserializes from a file, applies changes, then compares the changed object against the original object, possibly to implement a form of optimistic locking (although, since the file is unconditionally deleted at the end, I don't see how that would work).

Comment: @Jeronen bCurrent is passed by reference.

Comment: @JoshDavis Ah, mystery solved then -- something is done with the result after all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why does he deserialize again when dobj was never changed?

The *object* referenced by `dobj` **was** changed. It is the same object no matter whether you refer to it via `dobj` or `dccmcaltered`:

```
dccmcaltered = dobj as ASM001.MatSettings;
```

This just gets a different typed reference to the **same object**;

```
dccmcaltered.ObjectLocation = wpuiobj.ObjectLocation;
dccmcaltered.ObjectOffset = wpuiobj.ObjectOffset;
dccmcaltered.UserDefinedLocation = wpuiobj.UserDefinedLocation;
dccmcaltered.Locked = wpuiobj.Locked;
```

And now: the values are changed.

Note that `dccmcaltered` retains a reference to this original object, so those changes remain accessible even after `dobj` is assigned a different object.

Comment: Gotcha that's is were my lack in prgramming knowledge is. I didn't realize that changing dccmcaltered changed dobj. Thanks

Comment: @JoshDavis it is important to keep in mind the difference between *references* and *objects*. You can have 3000 references that all point to the same object. If you change that one object via *any* of those references: the change will be visible from the rest. There is, after all, *only one object*.

Comment: Again my lack of knowledge. I thought he created an object dccmcaltered then sets its members with the dobj as ASM001. I was thinking it was a copy of the dobj not a reference

Answer (score 2):

Somewhere later on he wants to compare the unaltered and the updated version.
First he deserializes to dccmcaltered , and sets some properties.
Then he deserializes to dccmcoriginal without setting these properties.

Glad I don't have to maintain this...
Good luck!

Yep, the comparison is (aargh):
bResult = Generics.IO.SerializerPlus.IsBinaryEqual(dccmcoriginal, dccmcaltered);

So you could just delete all about dccmcoriginal,
and verify if the properties need to change before actually changing them.

Answer (score 0):

Because he is changing firstly deserialized object `dobj` with lines like `dccmcaltered.ObjectLocation = wpuiobj.ObjectLocation;` so he loses "original" `dccmcaltered.ObjectLocation` values and "restores" them (into another object) with second deserialization... strange guy... cheers